# How to sum field across two DataFrames when the indexes don't line up?

Tags: python, pandas

I am brand new to complex data analysis in general, and to pandas in particular. I have a feeling that pandas should be able to handle this task easily, but my newbieness prevents me from seeing the path to a solution. I want to sum one column across two files at a given time each day, 3pm in this case. If a file doesn't have a record at 3pm that day, I want to use the previous record.

Let me give a concrete example. I have data in two CSV files. Here are a couple small examples:

```
datetime    value
2013-02-28 09:30:00 0.565019720442
2013-03-01 09:30:00 0.549536266504
2013-03-04 09:30:00 0.5023031467
2013-03-05 09:30:00 0.698370467751
2013-03-06 09:30:00 0.75834927162
2013-03-07 09:30:00 0.783620442226
2013-03-11 09:30:00 0.777265379462
2013-03-12 09:30:00 0.785787872851
2013-03-13 09:30:00 0.784873183044
2013-03-14 10:15:00 0.802959366653
2013-03-15 10:15:00 0.802959366653
2013-03-18 10:15:00 0.805413095911
2013-03-19 09:30:00 0.80816233134
2013-03-20 10:15:00 0.878912249996
2013-03-21 10:15:00 0.986393922571
```

and the other:

```
datetime    value
2013-02-28 05:00:00 0.0373634672097
2013-03-01 05:00:00 -0.24700085273
2013-03-04 05:00:00 -0.452964976056
2013-03-05 05:00:00 -0.2479288295
2013-03-06 05:00:00 -0.0326855588777
2013-03-07 05:00:00 0.0780461766619
2013-03-08 05:00:00 0.306247682656
2013-03-11 06:00:00 0.0194146154407
2013-03-12 05:30:00 0.0103653153719
2013-03-13 05:30:00 0.0350377752558
2013-03-14 05:30:00 0.0110884755383
2013-03-15 05:30:00 -0.173216846788
2013-03-19 05:30:00 -0.211785013352
2013-03-20 05:30:00 -0.891054563968
2013-03-21 05:30:00 -1.27207563599
2013-03-22 05:30:00 -1.28648629004
2013-03-25 05:30:00 -1.5459897419
```

Note that a) neither file actually has a 3pm record, and b) the two files don't always have records for any given day. (2013-03-08 is missing from the first file, while 2013-03-18 is missing from the second, and the first file ends before the second.) As output, I envision a dataframe like this (perhaps just the date without the time):

```
datetime    value
2013-Feb-28 15:00:00    0.6023831876517
2013-Mar-01 15:00:00    0.302535413774
2013-Mar-04 15:00:00    0.049338170644
2013-Mar-05 15:00:00    0.450441638251
2013-Mar-06 15:00:00    0.7256637127423
2013-Mar-07 15:00:00    0.8616666188879
2013-Mar-08 15:00:00    0.306247682656
2013-Mar-11 15:00:00    0.7966799949027
2013-Mar-12 15:00:00    0.7961531882229
2013-Mar-13 15:00:00    0.8199109582998
2013-Mar-14 15:00:00    0.8140478421913
2013-Mar-15 15:00:00    0.629742519865
2013-Mar-18 15:00:00    0.805413095911
2013-Mar-19 15:00:00    0.596377317988
2013-Mar-20 15:00:00    -0.012142313972
2013-Mar-21 15:00:00    -0.285681713419
2013-Mar-22 15:00:00    -1.28648629004
2013-Mar-25 15:00:00    -1.5459897419
```

I have a feeling this is perhaps a three-liner in pandas, but it's not at all clear to me how to do this. Further complicating my thinking about this problem, more complex CSV files might have multiple records for a single day (same date, different times). It seems that I need to somehow either generate a new pair of input dataframes with times at 15:00 and then sum across their values columns keying on just the date, or during the sum operation select the record with the greatest time on any given day with the time <= 15:00:00. Given that datetime.time objects can't be compared for magnitude, I suspect I might have to group rows together having the same date, then within each group, select only the row nearest to (but not greater than) 3pm. Kind of at that point my brain explodes.

I got nowhere looking at the documentation, as I don't really understand all the database-like operations pandas supports. Pointers to relevant documentation (especially tutorials) would be much appreciated.

Comment: By default csv's have an integer index. You should call `df1.set_index('datetime')` on both dataframes. Then you can add them normall `df1 + df2`.

Answer (score 1):

First combine your `DataFrames`:

```
df3 = df1.append(df2)
```

so that everything is in one table, next use the `groupby` to sum across timestamps:

```
df4 = df3.groupby('datetime').aggregate(sum)
```

now d4 has a `value` column that is the sum of all matching `datetime` columns.
Assuming you have the timestamps as `datetime` objects, you can do whatever filtering you like at any stage:

```
filtered = df[df['datetime'] < datetime.datetime(year, month, day, hour, minute, second)]
```

I'm not sure exactly what you are trying to do, you may need to parse your timestamp columns before filtering.

Comment: It's not clear to me how the aggregate(sum) call will work, as none of the datetime values are actually the same. All I wind up with is a DataFrame having same number of rows as the two DataFrames smashed together. Is there some way to filter the records in the two input DataFrames so they have a date column where the rows were selected from the original DataFrame on any given date with the greatest time <= 15:00?

Comment: To start with, is there some way the groupby() method can be called with a selector that keys off just the date() portion of the datetime column?

Comment: If you have a particular date in mind, you could filter before the groupby:
`filter = df['datetime'].apply(datetime.datetime.date) == datetime.date(2013,3,11)`
then apply the filter like so:
`df_filtered = df[filter]`
Additionally you could add a new column that is just the date and filter on that:
`df['date'] = df['datetime'].apply(datetime.datetime.date)`

Comment: No particular date in mind, but I want to group rows by date. Suppose I have two rows whose datetime fields have the same date (). I'd like them to group together.

Comment: I think the easiest way would be to create a date column using the comment above and group by that.